# Transportation Problem - Distribute Passengers via schedule over time

Tags: distribution, anylogic

I am fairly new to AnyLogic. I have the following problem:

I'm working on a transportation model and I have passengers that want to move from A to B to C to D. Now I have a schedule given where its stated, for example, from 10am-11am 450 people board on location A.

Now I have another distribution chart saying that from those 450 people 40% want to exit at B, 35% at C and 25% at D.

So now on the model in the blue box, passengers are created in "sourceFP" corresponding to the "scheduleFP". They then move to "queueFP" to wait for "pickup". When they got pickedup they travel to the yellow box to "dropoff1". There 40% of the passengers leave the train. From the remaining amount 35% leave at "dropoff2" and 25% at "dropoff3". (all coming from "sourceFP", without taking into the account the amount of passengers that get picked up at "pickup2"etc.)

My Problem now is, how to approach that so I can distribute the passengers from "sourceFP" accordingly to the given chart?
My idea now was to create some destination parameters and origin parameters so I can assign them accordingly when I create a function for the dropoff boxes. I also think there must be met some condition?

Sorry that I can't give any info about the codes I used yet as I'm working on it right now.

[Model so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UOQO.png)

Comment: Hi, happy to help but can you show us your model (screenshot) and let us know what you already tried, please? Also, turn this into a specific question, not a simple "I don't know how to do X". Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for inspiration :-)

Comment: Alright thanks for the advise. :) I put a link of the model in my original post. Thats what Im having so far and until now I tried it via the "SelectOutput In" and SelectOutputOut" blocks but this isnt working at all I suppose. So what I was thinking now is that maybe I can assign to my Passengers Agent 4 different "destination" parameters and build in a function in my "dropoff" block. does that sound possible?:)

Comment: well guess I would need a parameter from the source location aswell or?

Comment: Hi Sebastion, sounds possible but I won't check the model, please just share some screens. Happy to help but treat us as*very* busy colleagues so make our live as easy as possible to help you ;-)

Comment: Yaa definitely and Im already super thankful for the effort of helping me :). I might have expressed myself incorrect. "I put a link of the screenshot in my original post". I lack one reputation to post the screenshot directly :).

Comment: great, thanks. Now please make your question very specific to your screenshot. What should be dropped where? You can simply edit your original question (helps future readers) :-) And show any code that you already tried...

Comment: Alright. I hope I edited it now in a proper and comprehensive manner. Sorry for not being concrete enough from the beginning. I kinda knew I should have put more info. :)

Comment: Just found some topics here I will go through. Guess they are quite helpful. I keep you updated :)